# bluemixアップロードできない

Tags: bluemix

Finder上での情報では14.5MBとなっているファイルをアップロードしてwebアプリをIBM cloudで動かしたいのですがアップロードに失敗します．

```
bluemix app push hogehoge
```

まですると，

> ・・・省略
>   141.7M、27304 個のファイルをアップロードしています Done uploading OK
>
> 失敗 アプリケーションの再始動時にエラーが発生しました: サーバー・エラー、状況コード: 400、エラー・コード:
>   100005、メッセージ: You have exceeded your organization's memory limit: app
>   requested more memory than available

となり，エラーが出ます．
ライトプランで登録しているためメモリが足りていないということでしょうか？

ライトプランでも256MBまでは使用できると思うのですが，何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/100176

Comment: ファイルのアップロードには成功していて、アプリケーションの起動がメモリ不足で失敗しているのでは？インスタンス数を減らすなど調整できるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 対象ディレクトリの選択を誤っていました．コメントありがとうございました．